# Kable not printing captions anymore

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, kable

When a .rmd is rendered using `knitr::render()` instead of using the knitr function on RStudio, `kable()` doesn't create captions.
Here's a toy example for testing.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library('knitr')

```

`r kable(iris, caption = 'prova')`
````

Here's a picture of the outputs, using RStudio on the left and `render()` on the right:

[image]

Captioning was working correctly until few days ago, so I suspect it is due to an upgrade in knitr library I made yesterday.

```
devtools::session_info('rmarkdown')
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.383)           
 language en                          
 collate  it_IT.UTF-8                 
 tz       <NA>                        
 date     2017-10-11                  

Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 backports   1.1.1   2017-09-25 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 bitops      1.0-6   2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 caTools     1.17.1  2014-09-10 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 digest      0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 graphics  * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local         
 grDevices * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local         
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 knitr     * 1.17    2017-08-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 magrittr  * 1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 methods   * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local         
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 Rcpp        0.12.13 2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 rmarkdown * 1.6     2017-06-15 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 rprojroot   1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 stats     * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local         
 stringi     1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 stringr   * 1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 tools       3.4.0   2017-04-21 local         
 utils     * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local         
 yaml        2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0)

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘1.19.2.1’
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (table caption not printing when using the example above). Got it working by adding `format = 'pandoc'` to the `kable()` argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be an answer, but I just want to show that I cannot reproduce your problem:

[image: kable for Word output]

You should always report your session info.

```
> devtools::session_info('rmarkdown')
Session info --------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.383)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2017-10-11                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 backports   1.1.1   2017-09-25 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 bitops      1.0-6   2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 caTools     1.17.1  2014-09-10 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 digest      0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 graphics  * 3.4.2   2017-10-04 local         
 grDevices * 3.4.2   2017-10-04 local         
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 knitr       1.17    2017-08-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 methods   * 3.4.2   2017-10-04 local         
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 Rcpp        0.12.13 2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 rmarkdown   1.6     2017-06-15 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 rprojroot   1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 stats     * 3.4.2   2017-10-04 local         
 stringi     1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 stringr     1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 tools       3.4.2   2017-10-04 local         
 utils     * 3.4.2   2017-10-04 local         
 yaml        2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
```

Comment: So you are using the same OS and same versions of RStudio and rmarkdown as me. I have no idea what the problem could be then. Perhaps we have different versions of MS Office?

Comment: No, I didn't update Office since this problem appeared. I change the example, using html output and put results' image in the question.

Comment: can it be some mess I made with global options (just guessing)?

Comment: You said in your post that the problem only arose when using `rmarkdown::render()`. Do you mean using `render()` outside of RStudio? In that case, what is `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`? I suspect different versions of Pandoc were used when you compile the document with RStudio and `render()`.

Comment: The version is 1.19.2.1.  
I meant using render() (in RStudio) compared with the  knitr button in the RStudio .rmd editor.  
BTW I am ashamed to say that now captioning is working again. I can think of any significant action by my side apart turning off the computer (and therefore restarting R). Can't understand why this would fix the problem up though.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad the issue was gone anyway.